# PHP DateTime operations - set new timezone and deduct 24 hours

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am having a surprisingly hard time with the `datetime()` statement in PHP. What I am trying to achieve is to read the current server time (located in GMT-5), based on that time calculate the user specific date and time as per timezone, and then deduct 24 hours from the users current time. See an example below for users in London and Shanghai:

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone;

echo "<hr>";

$server_datetime = new \DateTime('now');  //located in America/New_York timezone - GMT-5
$server_newdate = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 day');
echo "Current Server DateTime: " . $server_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";
echo "If you deduct 24 hours you get " . $server_newdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";

$usersTimezone1 = 'Europe/London';  // GMT-0
$user_datetime1 = $server_datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1));
$user_newdate1 = ($server_datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1))->modify('-1 day'));
//$user_newdate1 = $user_datetime1->modify('-1 day');
echo "London User DateTime: " . $user_datetime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";
echo "If you deduct 24 hours you get " . $user_newdate1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";

$usersTimezone2 = 'Asia/Shanghai';  // GMT+8
$user_datetime2 = $server_datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone2));
$user_newdate2 = $user_datetime1->modify('-1 day');
echo "Shanghai User DateTime: " . $user_datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";
echo "If you deduct 24 hours you get " . $user_newdate2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

As you can see, the problem is that I cannot deduct the 24 hours directly from the $user_datetime variable which holds the current time of the user's timezone. Neither deducting from the variable directly nor creating a new instance of datetime() for this timezone seems to do the trick.

```
// attempt 1 - not working
    $user_datetime1 = $server_datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1));
    $user_newdate1 = ($server_datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1))->modify('-1 day'));

// attempt 2 - not working either
$user_datetime2 = $server_datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone2));
$user_newdate2 = $user_datetime1->modify('-1 day');
```

As soon as I start modifying the users datetime, the script will only return the current date and time of the users timezone, nothing else.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What you exactly want? Is this you want, lets say you have GMT+5:30 time you want to convert into another offset timing and deduct 24 hours?

Comment: @SahilGulati Yes, correct. If its lets say 31/12/2016 05:30 GMT-5, then its 31/12/2016 10:30 in GMT-0 (London). Now I want to deduct 24 hours from the London time, returning me 30/12/2016 10:30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a sort of best practice, you can use this:

```
$serverDateTime = new DateTime();

$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

$userDateTime = $serverDateTime->setTimezone($userTimezone);

$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');

echo $userDateTime->sub($dateInterval)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But if you want to subtract directly from the variable, you can use this one:

```
$serverDateTime = new DateTime();

$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

$userDateTime = $serverDateTime->setTimezone($userTimezone)->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $userDateTime;
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, but: can I adjust the interval from 1 day to 24 hours? the interval may be dynamic and depends on user input (24/48/72/96 hours)? the problem is that I have to echo both the users current time and the current time minus 24 hours, hence need to have at least 2 variables...

Comment: or just use Google ;) `PT24H` Thanks a lot mate, works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Asia/Kolkata +5:30
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");//set time zone
$istTime= strtotime(date("d-m-Y h:i:s"));//get timestamp in seconds
echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s");//16-03-2017 09:44:52

//Europe/London +0:00
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");//set new time zone
$dayBeforeTime= strtotime(date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$istTime))-86400;//get timestamp in seconds and subtracting 1 day seconds
echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$dayBeforeTime);//15-03-2017 04:14:52
```